# Конкретика в блоке с вопросом на главной странице

Tags: предложение, список-вопросов

На главной странице https://ru.stackoverflow.com с вопросами под заголовком каждого вопроса всегда есть подсказка, например (подчёркнуто красной линией):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, если изменён вопрос или ответ, то указано "изменён", но не уточняется, изменен то ли вопрос, то ли ответ. Мне кажется, что было бы удобнее, если бы конкретизировалось: "*ответ* изменён" или "*вопрос* изменён".

Возможно, я чего-то не замечаю или недопонимаю, но по мне так было бы проще понимать, где конкретно изменения в данном вопросе - изменён ли чей-то ответ или же непосредственно сам вопрос.

Comment: Так можно нажать на это слово и вас перекинут туда, где конкретно были изменения

Comment: @АндрейNOP если там будет удалённое сообщение, то ничего не увидите, если репы не хватает)